# MySQL: Creating regr_slope function

Tags: mysql

In MySQL I have added this function to calculate slope:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION regr_slope(x float, y float)
RETURNS float
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN 
  DECLARE n int;
  DECLARE sum_x float;
  DECLARE sum_y float;
  DECLARE sum_xx float;
  DECLARE sum_xy float;
  DECLARE slope float;

  SET n = COUNT(x);
  SET sum_x = SUM(x);
  SET sum_y = SUM(y);
  SET sum_xx = SUM(x*x);
  SET sum_xy = SUM(x*y);

  SET slope = (n * sum_xy - sum_x * sum_y) / (n * sum_xx - POWER(sum_x, 2));

  RETURN slope;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

However, when I use it like this:

```
SELECT regr_slope(pd.avg_velocity, pd.load_kg) FROM push_data
```

I get the error *Invalid use of group function*.
What could be the reason for this?

Comment: `x` and `y` are single numbers, not sets. you can't use `sum` or `count` or any of the other `group functions` on them. your procedure will be called once for each row in `push_data`, not once for all of the data in the table.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean.